# I am not able to connect to Internet through application code even after setting proxy in emulator

Tags: android

I am only able to connect internet through emulator browser. I am not able to connect to Internet through application code even after setting proxy in emulator and also inserting values to system table. It is throwing unknown host exception. I tried with one more option that setting proxy in application Run Configuration. But it is throwing Authentication scheme ntlm not supported error. I have given Internet permission in manifest also. Please let me know some solution for connecting Internet through code.

Code

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WebView mWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("google.com";);
    }
}
```

Exception thrown

```
02-04 12:33:23.230: ERROR/CheckinTask(177): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0)
02-04 12:33:23.230: ERROR/CheckinTask(177): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /209.85.153.100:443 timed out
02-04 12:33:23.230: ERROR/CheckinTask(177):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
```

Comment: can you pls put code frm which you r connecting and the proper logcat o/p

Comment: You said it's throwing `Authentication scheme ntlm not supported`. It has to do something with your problem

Comment: the code im using is : public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}

Comment: ERROR/CheckinTask(174): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0)
 ERROR/CheckinTask(174): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /64.233.169.113:443 timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was due to firewall settings in my system. I also added the proxy server details in emulators network settings.

Comment: what was the problem in ur firewall? i am also getting the same error... can u help me to get rid of that?

Comment: I also have such problem please describe in details, how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Make proxy configuration in the emulator settings only when you are accessing the internet behind the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the permission for internet as well

Comment: I had same issue on college network, everything goes through proxy which needs authentication

Answer (score 0):

are you able to call a web page with the build in browser (the "normal" browser)? If not then your code is not the problem, try this first.

Comment: Iam able to view web pages through the emulators browser. When i call the web page from within a application, iam getting this exception.

Comment: The real problem was due to some network settings in my system. Spend half a day trying to figure out what am i doing wrong. Now everthing is working fine. Thanks for all ur help.